# jcifs.smb.SmbException: Access is Denied

Tags: java

I have a requirement where i have to copy a file from my local workspace to a network drive. i have all working credentials to open up the network drive and see, i am using JCIF methods to achieve this but unfortunately when i run the below code am getting the access denied exception

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("D:\\sampletext.txt");
        try {
            createCopyOnNetwork("prestige", "sannayalap", "Ci**@***", "D:\\sampletext.txt", "smb://10.28.41.**//d$//CDSBatches//test"); 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

public static boolean createCopyOnNetwork(String domain,String username,String password,String src, String dest) throws Exception
    {
        SmbFileOutputStream out = null;
        BufferedInputStream inBuf = null;
        try{
            NtlmPasswordAuthentication authentication = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(domain,username,password); // replace with actual values  
            SmbFile file = new SmbFile(dest, authentication); // note the different format
            inBuf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(src));
            out = (SmbFileOutputStream)file.getOutputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[5242880];
            int len;
            while ((len = inBuf.read(buf)) > 0){
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally{
            try{
                if(inBuf!=null)
                    inBuf.close();
                if(out!=null)
                    out.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {}
        }
        System.out.print("\n File copied to destination");
        return true;
    }
```

when i run this am getting this exception

```
jcifs.smb.SmbException: Access is denied.
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.checkStatus(SmbTransport.java:563)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:664)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:238)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.send(SmbTree.java:119)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.send(SmbFile.java:775)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open0(SmbFile.java:992)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open(SmbFile.java:1009)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:142)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:97)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:67)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.getOutputStream(SmbFile.java:2856)
    at dev.copyFileRemote.createCopyOnNetwork(copyFileRemote.java:36)
    at dev.copyFileRemote.main(copyFileRemote.java:141)
```

if any one have any idea on how to copy files to network drive then please help in this. also please suggest if you know any other alternative approaches to acheive this.